# F# can't implement interface with object expression when method parameter is unit

Tags: f#

I cannot find a way of implementing an interface with an object expression when it contains a method with no types that can refer to the type for which the implementation is being put into place. A method with signature `unit -> string` is a simple example. Example code below:

```
type AsString =
    abstract member asString: unit -> string
    
type AsString2<'T> =
    abstract member asString: 'T -> string

type SomeDu =
    | A of int
    | B of string
    | C of float
    interface AsString
        with member self.asString () =
                match self with
                | A a -> string a
                | B b -> b
                | C c -> string c
    interface AsString2<SomeDu>
        with member self.asString x =
                if not (x = self) then failwith "argument must be the member container"
                match self with
                | A a -> string a
                | B b -> b
                | C c -> string c

//this expression was expected to have type AsString but here has type SomeDU            
let implSomeDU = 
    {new AsString with
        member self.asString () =
            match self with
            | A a -> string a
            | B b -> b
            | C c -> string c}
```

If I attempt to refer to the implementing type as I've done with `AsString2` then no problem with object expressions, but the implementation on the DU now has a requirement that I cannot express in the type system: the argument has to be the DU instance or the method has no value.

Is there any trick that'd let me implement `AsString` as an object expression for SomeDu?

Comment: Why would you not just override Object.ToString()?

Comment: this is just an example, my question is about how to deal with this case in general. The signature could have been `unit -> SomeRecordType` as well.

Comment: "Is there any trick that'd let me implement AsString as an object expression for SomeDu?": I'm not sure what you're aiming for here. An object expression can't be made "for" an existing type. An object expression is essentially a new, anonymous class, with a single instance. It seems like what you're trying to do is more like an extension method, but you can't implement an interface in an extension method, so you may be out of luck.

Comment: brianberns thanks. I usually find myself defining interfaces with a parameterised type being the first parameter's type, as in `'T -> string` above, which is an object expression friendly approach. I just realised (thought)  that the blanket statement "you can implement interfaces on classes, or in object expressions" is not entirely accurate due to the above case and wanted to clarify my understanding. I thought there may be some dark magic trick that'd let me associate an object expression to a particular type for which the interface is implemented. Just curious, that's all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When implementing an interface using an object expression, the type of `this` is always going to be the interface and nothing else - unlike when implementing an interface in some other type (where `this` refers to the current value), in case of object expressions, the "current value" is just the interface implementation.

If you want to implement an interface in an existing type, do that by implementing it in the type itself.

If you want to get an implementation of an interface based on some other value, you can write a function that takes the value and implements the interface using object expression.

In your case, your function in the second case would look like this:

```
type AsString =
  abstract member asString: unit -> string

type SomeDu =
  | A of int
  | B of string
  | C of float

let implSomeDU someDu = 
  { new AsString with
      member self.asString () =
          match someDu with
          | A a -> string a
          | B b -> b
          | C c -> string c }
```

Comment: Excellent!, this is exactly the kind of smart stuff I knew someone would be able to come up with :) Thanks a lot Tomas.